# character-set-server and mysql's config file

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I am running `mysql -u root -p` (on Ubuntu 12.05), and I keep on getting this error message:

```
mysql: unknown variable 'character-set-server=utf8'
```

Indeed in my `my.cnf` file I set it up because I had a message occurring when setting `default-set-server=utf8` which is now deprecated. Here's my `my.cnf` file:

```
[client]
  port            = 3306
  socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  character-set-server = utf8
[mysqld]
  #
  # * Basic Settings
  #
  user            = mysql
  pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  port            = 3306
  basedir         = /usr
  datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
  tmpdir          = /tmp
  skip-external-locking
  collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
  character-set-server = utf8
  init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: You are setting the `character-set-server` under the `[client]` section of your `my.cnf`.  Perhaps you intended to set `character-set-client` there?

Answer (score 3):

you need to remove `character-set-server = utf8` under client you already have one for in `[mysqld]` and make sure to restart the SID after changing the cnf file